# Sam Fisher voice actor

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

I just started playing the new Splinter Cell Blacklist. And I wonder if the voice actor of Sam Fisher is a new voice actor.

**Is there a new voice actor for Sam Fisher in Splinter Cell Blacklist?**

It does not seem to be the same "darkish" voice as in the other games of the series.

Comment: And it gets a downvote because?

Comment: It's a trivial question, something that can be found out with a quick search.

Comment: @MBraedley Can you point me in the direction that trivial questions arent welcome here?

Comment: @AtlasEU They're perfectly *welcome* here. That doesn't mean that everyone who votes on them has to *like them*.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz They sure don't have to :) I just assumed it got a down vote due to the fact that it was not welcome here. There are lots of questions that I don't like, but I wouldn't down vote every question that I don't like or find trivial.

Comment: @AtlasEU Close votes mean something is *wrong*. Downvotes might mean there's something you can improve, but in those cases, generally, someone will leave a comment. Most of the time, they just mean "I don't like it."

Comment: To clear things up, I quote the downvote tooltip: "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" technically, there's nothing wrong with trivial questions...except that they lack research effort in most cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the voice actor has changed.

[Michael Ironside](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000461/) voiced Sam Fisher in all of the previous Splinter Cell games.

The new VA for Blacklist is [Eric Johnson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0425053).